# How to replace / overwrite a Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, controls

I'm currently working on my first WPF application.

I have created a blank canvas control in the "Designer" called "canvas1".

At runtime I'm dynamically creating a new canvas (with lots of children) with my function "GenTechnicalDrawing()".

I figured I could just replace the canvas by another canvas, but that doesn's seem to work.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    Canvas complicatedCanvas = GenTechnicalDrawing();
    canvas1 = complicatedCanvas;
}
```

It doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't change the display either.

What's the best approch to solve this Problem?

Thanks
Karl

PS: My XAML

```
<Grid Name="myGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.492">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>            
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Canvas Name="canvas1"  Width="100" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
    </Viewbox>

    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="clear" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canvas1` is just a field in your Window class. So what you're doing is in fact point it to another canvas instance while the old canvas is still held by some other property of some element (such as held by `Content` property of the Window). To change the content, you have to access to the container of the old canvas and replace the content with the new canvas.

E.g: if you use a `Grid` as the container, try the following code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    Canvas complicatedCanvas = GenTechnicalDrawing();
    var grid = canvas1.Parent as Grid;
    if(grid != null){
       var column = Grid.GetColumn(canvas1);
       var row = Grid.GetRow(canvas1);
       var colSpan = Grid.GetColumnSpan(canvas1);
       var rowSpan = Grid.GetRowSpan(canvas1);
       grid.Children.Remove(canvas1); //remove old canvas
       grid.Children.Add(complicatedCanvas);//add new canvas
       Grid.SetColumn(complicatedCanvas, column);
       Grid.SetRow(complicatedCanvas, row);
       Grid.SetColumnSpan(complicatedCanvas, colSpan);
       Gid.SetRowSpan(complicatedCanvas, rowSpan);
    }
}
```

However your updated XAML code shows that the ***direct*** container here is a `Viewbox` so the code can be much simpler like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    Canvas complicatedCanvas = GenTechnicalDrawing();
    var vb = canvas1.Parent as Viewbox;
    if(vb != null){
       vb.Child = complicatedCanvas;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I do that: access the container of the old canvas and replace the content with the new canvas.

Comment: @KarlW it depends on which type of container you use here, e.g: ContentControl, ItemsControl, ...

Comment: @KarlW in fact the ***direct*** container here is a `Viewbox`, so it's much simpler, see the second code above.